# Задача по Python. Количество трактовок данной последовательности

Tags: python, алгоритм

Такая вот задача. Не могу ни как до конца продумать алгоритм ее решения.

[image: фвафыва]

```py
string = input()     
dont_repeat = []     
count = 0

for unit in string:
    if int(unit) != 0 and unit not in dont_repeat:
        dont_repeat.append(unit)
count += 1
for i in range(len(string)):
    dozen = string[i : i + 2]
    if int(dozen) >= 10 and int(dozen) <= 33 and dozen not in dont_repeat:
        dont_repeat.append(dozen)
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Это решение рабочее только для числа, которое прописано в условии картинки. А для других чисел не могу сообразить как сделать...

Comment: Ну, можно работать рекурсивно, не скажу только, насколько быстро. Встретили что-то, что можно трактовать и как однозначное число, и как двузначное - вызываем функцию для обоих вариантов. В Python не силен, так что текст не просите :)

Comment: Где ваш код? что у вас не получается? учебные задачи за вас здесь никто решать не будет. Если не дополните вопрос своим решением, он будет закрыт.

Comment: @strawdog Исправил

Comment: @Harry Можете написать на любом другом языке, думаю алгоритм рекурсии станет визуально понятным

Comment: Почему ответ для 90135 - 3? Возможных вариантов 2: 9-0-1-3-5 и 9-0-13-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def CalculateCountInNumber(str, startInd, endInd):
    if startInd > endInd:
        return 1

    result = CalculateCountInNumber(str, startInd + 1, endInd)

    if startInd + 1 <= endInd and int(str[startInd : startInd + 2]) <= 33:
        result += CalculateCountInNumber(str, startInd + 2, endInd)
    return result


def test(str):
    result = 1
    zeroInd = -1

    i = 0
    while i <= len(str):
        if i == len(str) or str[i] == "0":
            result *= CalculateCountInNumber(str, zeroInd + 1, i - 1)
            zeroInd = i
        i += 1

    print(result)
```

Comment: опять рекурсия. это же дп, стандартное дп.

Answer (score 0):

На С/С++ - что-то вроде

```
int counts(const char * s)
{
    if (s[0] == 0) return 1;
    if (s[1] == 0) return counts(s+1);
    if (s[0] >  '3') return counts(s+1);
    if (s[0] == '3' && s[1] > '3') return counts(s+1);
    if (s[0] == '0' || s[0] > '3') return counts(s+1);
    if (s[0] == '1' || s[0] == '2') return counts(s+1) + counts(s+2);
    return counts(s+1) + counts(s+2);
}
```

Сильно не тестировал - поэтому мое стандартное завершение:
*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*

Comment: Слишком долгое решение + тут нужна длинка.

Comment: @СашаНовожилов Добавляем мемоизацию - вот и ДП :) Что подразумевается под "длинка"?

Answer (score 0):

Решение за `O(n)`

```
s = input() + 'a'
n = len(s) - 1
vary = [-1] * n
def count(s, idx):
    if idx == n:
        return 1
    if idx > n:
        return 0
    if vary[idx] != -1:
        return vary[idx]
    c = count(s, idx + 1)
    if s[idx] > '0' and s[idx] < '3':
        c += count(s, idx + 2)
    if s[idx] == '3' and s[idx+1] < '4':
        c += count(s, idx + 2)
    vary[idx] = c
    return c
print(count(s, 0))
```